# To access Web sites on the local IIS Web server, you must run Visual Studio under an Administrator account

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to open a project in Visual studio 2012 but Load failed i think this project is using the "Local IIS Web Server",so i think it need the Admin rights. But i don't have the admin rights.

getting this error

> To access Web sites on the local IIS Web server, you must run Visual
>   Studio under an Administrator account.

IS there any way that i can run the "Local IIS web server" without the admin privileges?

Comment: You can use the development web server, IIS Express or manually configure IIS.

Comment: @jessehouwing i have to use the IIS Web Server and if i use the IIS express then not able to assign the port 80 or any port less than 1024. but i need to assign the port number 80. this is my task

Comment: Go to the project properties and then to the "Web" tab. In there you can change how the project runs. If you cannot load the project to do this, then you will have to edit the project file manually (make a new project and copy its web settings).

Comment: Stop IIS if you want to use Port 80

Comment: Open the IIS management console, stop the site that is running on port 80. Configure a new site int he webroot of your Visual Studio project and Visual Studio can use that. In order to debug you will still need to be an administrator, since only those can attach to a process that's running in a different user context.

Comment: If its a local development web server, why do you even care if its port 80?

Comment: @StingyJack i need to use the Local IIS web server because the system because on the project there are multiple person working. Other persons might have admin rights but if i use the VIsual Studio dev server and check in the code then there might be problem for other developer. So i need the generic solution

Comment: Your approach to development is what is causing you to have this problem. You should have your code, and it should be separate from another developers code (even on the same machine), and it should be hosted in its own space (its own URL and Port - not 80) especially if its on the same machine.